# Can't make OpenGL Buffer Array work - glVertex works

Tags: c++, opengl

I have an Eigen::MatrixXf with vertices (N*3) and faces (N*3) as variables mvTemp2 and mF.

If I draw my vertices regularly, they give the correct output based on the code below:

```
while(1){
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glShadeModel( GL_SMOOTH );
    glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );

    glViewport( 0, 0, (float)renderWidth/1, (float)renderHeight/1. );
    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective( 60, (float)renderWidth/(float)renderHeight, 0.1, 10000. );
    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();

    glPolygonMode( GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE );
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(0,-0.5,-0.5);
//        glBindVertexArray(vao);
//        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indexdata.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,     (void*)0);

    for(int i=0; i<smpl.mF.rows(); i++){
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        for(int j=0; j<smpl.mF.cols(); j++){
            indexdata.push_back(smpl.mF(i,j)+1);

        }
        glVertex3fv((const GLfloat*)&vertexdata[smpl.mF(i,0)].position);
        glVertex3fv((const GLfloat*)&vertexdata[smpl.mF(i,1)].position);
        glVertex3fv((const GLfloat*)&vertexdata[smpl.mF(i,2)].position);
        glEnd();
    }

    glPopMatrix();

    glutSwapBuffers();
    glutPostRedisplay();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
    glutMainLoopEvent();
}
```

[image]

However, if I use vertex buffers, i get rubbish output:

```
// Iterate v
for(int i=0; i<smpl.mVTemp2.rows(); i++){
    Vertex v;
    for(int j=0; j<smpl.mVTemp2.cols(); j++){
        v.position[j] = smpl.mVTemp2(i,j);
    }
    vertexdata.push_back(v);
}

std::vector<GLubyte> indexdata;

// Iterate f
for(int i=0; i<smpl.mF.rows(); i++){
    for(int j=0; j<smpl.mF.cols(); j++){
        indexdata.push_back(smpl.mF(i,j));
    }
}

// Create and bind a VAO
GLuint vao;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);

// Create and bind a BO for vertex data
GLuint vbuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &vbuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbuffer);

// copy data into the buffer object
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexdata.size() * sizeof(Vertex), &vertexdata[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// set up vertex attributes
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, position)); // vertices
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_TRUE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, normal)); // normals
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, texcoord)); // normals

// Create and bind a BO for index data
GLuint ibuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &ibuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibuffer);

// copy data into the buffer object
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexdata.size() * sizeof(GLubyte), &indexdata[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindVertexArray(0);

while(1){
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glShadeModel( GL_SMOOTH );
    glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );

    glViewport( 0, 0, (float)renderWidth/1, (float)renderHeight/1. );
    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective( 60, (float)renderWidth/(float)renderHeight, 0.1, 10000. );
    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();

    glPolygonMode( GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE );
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(0,-0.5,-0.5);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indexdata.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (void*)0);
    glPopMatrix();

    glutSwapBuffers();
    glutPostRedisplay();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
    glutMainLoopEvent();
}
```

[image]

I can't understand what I am doing wrong. I am able to draw the faces normally with regular old glVertex and it works, but is too slow. So I want to use vertex buffers, but the code always gives junk output. Why is this the case?
**EDIT:**

I have solved the problem, however my normals are now wrong. If I draw it normally with Vertex and Normal calls, it works:

```
std::vector<Vertex> vertexdata;
for(int i=0; i<object.vertices.size(); i++){
    Vertex v;
    v.position[0] = object.vertices.at(i).coords[0];
    v.position[1] = object.vertices.at(i).coords[1];
    v.position[2] = object.vertices.at(i).coords[2];
    v.normal[0] = object.computedNormals.at(i).coords[0];
    v.normal[1] = object.computedNormals.at(i).coords[1];
    v.normal[2] = object.computedNormals.at(i).coords[2];
    vertexdata.push_back(v);
}

std::vector<GLushort> indexdata;
for(int i=0; i<object.faces.size(); i++){
    OBJFace& face = object.faces.at(i);
    indexdata.push_back(face.items[0].vertexIndex);
    indexdata.push_back(face.items[1].vertexIndex);
    indexdata.push_back(face.items[2].vertexIndex);

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glNormal3fv(vertexdata[face.items[0].vertexIndex].normal);
    glVertex3fv(vertexdata[face.items[0].vertexIndex].position);
    glNormal3fv(vertexdata[face.items[1].vertexIndex].normal);
    glVertex3fv(vertexdata[face.items[1].vertexIndex].position);
    glNormal3fv(vertexdata[face.items[2].vertexIndex].normal);
    glVertex3fv(vertexdata[face.items[2].vertexIndex].position);
    glEnd();
}
```

[image]

However, if I use it with Vertex Buffers, it does not:

```
std::vector<Vertex> vertexdata;
for(int i=0; i<object.vertices.size(); i++){
    Vertex v;
    v.position[0] = object.vertices.at(i).coords[0];
    v.position[1] = object.vertices.at(i).coords[1];
    v.position[2] = object.vertices.at(i).coords[2];
    v.normal[0] = object.computedNormals.at(i).coords[0];
    v.normal[1] = object.computedNormals.at(i).coords[1];
    v.normal[2] = object.computedNormals.at(i).coords[2];
    vertexdata.push_back(v);
}

std::vector<GLushort> indexdata;
for(int i=0; i<object.faces.size(); i++){
    OBJFace& face = object.faces.at(i);
    indexdata.push_back(face.items[0].vertexIndex);
    indexdata.push_back(face.items[1].vertexIndex);
    indexdata.push_back(face.items[2].vertexIndex);
}

glBindVertexArray(vao);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbuffer);

// copy data into the buffer object
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexdata.size() * sizeof(Vertex), &vertexdata[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// set up vertex attributes
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, position)); // vertices
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, normal)); // normals
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, texcoord)); // normals

// Create and bind a BO for index data
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibuffer);

// copy data into the buffer object
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexdata.size() * sizeof(GLushort), &indexdata[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindVertexArray(0);

glBindVertexArray(vao);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indexdata.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,     (void*)0);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In addition to the answer of Nicol Bolas**:

It looks like as the number of indices is too much to encode them in bytes (`GLubyte`). A byte can store data in the range [0, 255], so only 256 indices can be encoded in a byte. Use `GLushort` instead. The range of `GLushort` is [0, 65535]:

```
std::vector<GLushort> indexdata;

....

GLuint ibuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &ibuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibuffer);

glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexdata.size()*sizeof(GLushort),
    indexdata.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

....

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indexdata.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (void*)0);
```

Comment: wow that works now, thanks alot. Its weird because i tries GLUint and that does not work either

Comment: Unfortunately, my normals seem incorrect. The mesh is black when i draw it normally. Am i doing something wrong? I have edited the code to push in normals too

Comment: @raaj Are the normal vecors normalized? Probably setting *normalize* to `GL_TRUE` does not do, what you expect it to do. See [OpenGL Vertex Attributes - Normalisation](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/9792/opengl-vertex-attributes-normalisation)

Comment: I have edited my question to include my changed code. Are you able to help me take a look at that

Comment: @raaj Of course, you have to consider the answer of Nicol Bolas too.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using shaders for vertex processing. As such, generic vertex attributes (as provided by `VertexAttrib` functions) cannot be used. So, you can either switch to using shaders, or use fixed-function attributes:

```
// set up vertex attributes
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, position)); // vertices
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, normal)); // normals
glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, texcoord)); // normals
```

Comment: I replaced VertexAttrib with that, and I still get the same result